# How to compile code with implicits and existentials types with 2.13

Tags: scala, implicit, existential-type, singleton-type, scala-2.13

**upd** I have a function that accepts types with existentials:

```
trait QueryValue[V]

trait QueryValueFormats {
  implicit object IntQueryValue extends QueryValue[Int]
  implicit object StringQueryValue extends QueryValue[String]
}

trait Magnets {
  trait NumericCol[C]
  implicit def numericFromInt[T <: Int](s: T)(implicit evidence: QueryValue[T]): NumericCol[T] = new NumericCol[T] {}
  implicit def numericFromString[T <: String](s: T)(implicit evidence: QueryValue[T]): NumericCol[T] = new NumericCol[T] {}
}

object Hello extends App with  Magnets with QueryValueFormats {
  //function accept only existentials
  def existentialsOnly(coln: NumericCol[_]*): Unit = println("stub")

  existentialsOnly(1, "str")//not compiles
}
```

It compiles with 2.12, but with 2.13 - not:

```
[error] ..//Hello.scala:21:20: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Int(1)
[error]  required: example.Hello.NumericCol[_]
[error]   existentialsOnly(1, "str")
[error]
```

I try to remove existentials(Just some tryings):

```
def existentialsOnly[T: ClassTag](coln: NumericCol[T]*): Unit
```

And this make code compilable, but if `coln` have single type only. E.g:

```
existentialsOnly("str", "str")
```

So, how properly use existentials in first case? Does current usage wrong for 2.13?

Comment: Seems to work without existential: `val s: NumericCol[Int] = 2`

Comment: When asking questions, never just say “it doesn't work” or the equivalent, always give the complete exact text of the actual error message you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

The thing seems to be that in 2.13 singleton types are treated a little less conservatively than in 2.12.

The error

```
Error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: App.Hello.NumericCol[_]
    existentialsOnly(1, "str")
```

means that in 2.13 it's not inferred that `1` in `existentialsOnly(1, "str")` has type `Int` (and therefore `NumericCol[Int]` because of implicit conversion) rather than singleton type `Int(1)`.

If you add hints

```
existentialsOnly(1: Int, "str": String)
```

will compile in 2.13.

Similarly you can replace `numericFromInt` and `numericFromString` with

```
implicit def numericFrom[U, T <: U](s: T)(implicit evidence: QueryValue[U]): NumericCol[T] = new NumericCol[T] {}
```

or

```
implicit def numericFrom[T](s: T)(implicit evidence: QueryValue[_ >: T]): NumericCol[T] = new NumericCol[T] {}
```

in both 2.12 and 2.13 but with

```
implicit def numericFrom[T](s: T)(implicit evidence: QueryValue[T]): NumericCol[T] = new NumericCol[T] {}
```

(without hints) only in 2.12.